# Does $-\frac12\cos(2x)=\sin^2(x)$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int2\sin x\cos x\mathrm dx$$
                                                                            $1$:Consider $2\sin x\cos x=\sin(2x)$  Then the integration is $-\frac12\cos(2x)$

$2$: Consider  $2\sin x\cos x=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sin^2(x)$ Then the integration is $\sin^2(x)$

If it is true then 
$-\frac12\cos(2x)=\sin^2(x)$
 then 
$-\frac12(1+2\sin^2(x))=\sin^2(x)$,$-\frac12=\sin^2{x}$, $-\frac12=1$

Comment: Well, $-\frac12$ and $1$ are the same up to a *constant of integration*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with indefinite integral therefore you have to take into account that while integrating we have to add a constant of integration. To be precise we got that

\begin{align*}
\int 2\sin x\cos x\mathrm dx&=\int 2\sin x\cos x\mathrm dx\\
\int \sin(2x)\mathrm dx&=\int \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\sin^2(x)\right)\mathrm dx\\
-\frac12\cos(2x)+c_1&=\sin^2(x)+c_2\\
-\frac12\cos(2x)&=\sin^2(x)+c
\end{align*}

To determine the constant of integration in this case we can follow your own attempt by expanding the $\cos(2x)$, even though you have made a minor mistake there, term to get

\begin{align*}
-\frac12\cos(2x)&=\sin^2(x)+c\\
-\frac12(1-2\sin^2(x))&=\sin^2(x)+c\\
c&=-\frac12
\end{align*}

We just proved the Half-Angle Formula since we can now conclude that

> $$\sin^2(x)=\frac12-\frac12\cos(2x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}2$$

Which is basically all what was missing.